# Correcting "Python support for SSL and HTTPS is not installed"

Tags: mac-osx, python, mercurial

I was working with mercurial tonight on Apple's OS X (10.5), and received this error message while attempting to clone from a repository over SSL:

```
Python support for SSL and HTTPS is not installed
```

Any ideas as to how I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to correct this behavior like by installing the py25-socket-ssl port.  You can do so by running the following on the command prompt:

```
sudo port install py25-socket-ssl
```